# Wolfram Engine interface in Delphi Program Code

Tags: user-interface, free-wolfram-engine

I am unable to locate documentation on how to link the Wolfram Engine into a compiled language, specifically for Delphi code for a Delphi windows application (running in windows 10) using the Wolfram Engine as a statically linked sub-system (or as a linked dll).

I have the latest Wolfram system and the new Wolfram Engine installed.  I also have the latest Delphi IDE (10.2.4).

Can someone point me to such documentation or provide a starting point?